# Return a value from this promise

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, promise, pug

This might be a stupid question but no one at school knows how to do it so.
I have this code that works perfectly (it sends the table of objects `potentials` and I can work with it client side) But I remembered that I need another as well (`userData`).
So I tried to declare it as a `const` and then logging it right before my `res.render` but it's `undefined`. Our group of students is not very familiar with promises so far so maybe we are missing something here.
Anyway here's my code, any help ?? Thank you.

```
function matchaSearch (pool, username) {
return suggestUsers(pool, username)
  .then((searcherInfos) => {
     userData = [...searcherInfos]
    if (userData[0].sex === 'm' && userData[0].orientation === 's') {
      return lookForSF(pool, username)
    } else if ((userData[0].sex) && userData[0].orientation === 'b') {
      return lookForbothCauseImB(pool, username)
    } else if ((userData[0].sex) === 'f' && userData[0].orientation === 's') {
      return lookForSM(pool, username)
    } else if ((userData[0].sex) === 'm' && userData[0].orientation === 'g') {
      return lookForGM(pool, username)
    } else if ((userData[0].sex) === 'f' && userData[0].orientation === 'g') {
      return lookforGF(pool, username)
    }
  })
  .then((rows) => {
    var potentials = rows;
    return (potentials)
  })
}

router.post('/matchaSearch', function (req, res) {
const userData = []
matchaSearch(pool, session.uniqueID)
.then((potentials) => {
  console.log(userData);
  res.render('./userMatch', {potentials, userData})
})
.catch((err) => {
  console.error('error', err)
  res.status(500).send("we don't have any suggestions for you so far")
})
})
```

Comment: `userData` is empty array?

Comment: actually I just found an answer. Sorry for posting this.
I can call my function from a variable just before my res.render and then move it.

Comment: Did your question get answered?

Answer (score 0):

You are not using `Promise` the right way, there is nothing like return in that. Example for your code can be

```
var searcherInfosPro = (searcherInfos)=>{
  return new Promise((fullfill,reject)=>{
    userData = [...searcherInfos];
    if (userData[0].sex === 'm' && userData[0].orientation === 's') {
      fullfill([pool,username]);
    }else if((userData[0].sex) && userData[0].orientation === 'b') {
      fullfill([pool,username]);
    }else{
      reject((new Error("Some error detected"));
    }
  });
}
```

And you can call that using

```
suggestUsers(pool, username)
  .then(searcherInfosPro)
  .then((rows) => {
    var [pool,username] = rows;
    return (potentials)
  })
  .catch((ex)=>{
    console.log(ex.message);
  });
```

Looking at your code, it wasn't a lot clear to me so the above code is a short version on how to properly use promise and pass data to next. Also remember to always use `catch` for any errors.

> From above code the `else` case would invoke and error and print `Some error detected`.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I did, it works for me :

```
router.post('/matchaSearch', function (req, res) {

matchaSearch(pool, session.uniqueID)
.then((potentials) => {
  userData = suggestUsers(pool, username)
    .then((rows) => {
      res.render('./userMatch', {potentials, rows})
    })


})
.catch((err) => {
  console.error('error', err)
  res.status(500).send("we don't have any suggestions for you so far")
})
})
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you found an answer for part of your problem.  I thought I'd show you a cleaner way to do this that offers the following improvements:

1. Replace all your if/else clauses with a lookup table.
2. Remove the side effect programming of trying to set `userData` into a higher scoped variable so you can pick it up later.
3. How to return more than one value from a promise (by wrapping them in an object).

Code:

```
const fnLookup = {
    'ms': lookForSF,
    'fs': lookForSM,
    'mg': lookForGM,
    'fg': lookForGF,
    'mb': lookForbothCauseImB,
    'fb': lookForbothCauseImB
};


function matchaSearch (pool, username) {
    return suggestUsers(pool, username).then(searcherInfos => {
        let userData = [...searcherInfos];
        let fn = fnLookup[userData[0].sex + userData[0].orientation];
        if (fn) {
            return fn(pool, username).then(potentials => {
                return {potentials, userData};
            });
        } else {
            throw new Error(`Unexpected values for sex ${userData[0].sex} or orientation ${userData[0].orientation}`);
        }
    });
}

router.post('/matchaSearch', (req, res) => {
    matchaSearch(pool, session.uniqueID).then(data => {
        console.log(data.userData);
        res.render('./userMatch', data);
    }).catch(err => {
        console.error('error', err)
        res.status(500).send("we don't have any suggestions for you so far")
    });
});
```